# Can u explain the line, " A voltage source likes open circuit load and hates short circuit load."

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, short-circuits

Can u explain the line, " A voltage source likes open circuit load and hates short circuit load." In my textbook it just says 'for obvious reasons'

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a simple circuit: a voltage source $V$ and a resistence (load) $R$.
From Ohm's law, you will have that there is a circulating current $I$ such that
$$I=V/R$$.
So far so good. Now, the power $P$ (energy spent per unit time) of a circuit is given by

$$P=I^2 R=V^2/R$$
where for the last equality I used the relationship between current and voltage that we found before.

This means that if $R\ll1$ (as in a short circuit, where $R\sim0$) then the power can be very big ($P\sim\infty$), so that in the same time $T$ the energy $E$ you spend (at constant voltage $V$ as we usually expect in a battery), which is $$E=PT=(V^2/R)T$$ can be very big is $R$ (the load) is very small. Because batteries contain a finite amount of energy $E_0$, the smaller the load, the fastest the battery will drain. The time $T_0$ it takes for the battery to be drained is indeed
$$T=E_0/P=ER/V^2$$
and you see it depends linearly on the load.

As a quick example, if $R=1$ Ohm and $V=1$ volt it takes $1$ s to dissipate $E_0=1$ Joule. If the load now is $1$ mOhm it will take $1$ ms.

On the other hand, if the circuit is open ($R=\infty$) or if the load is very big ($R\gg1$) the time it takes is much longer (in principle, $T_0=\infty$ if the circuit is open). However of course batteries have a shelf life depending on chemical reactions, etc.

This is not perfectly true in the real world, where voltage also decreases as the battery dies, but the general principle remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

A battery has a long shelf life with no load but is quickly drained (and may overheat and explode) if the terminals are shorted. A power supply is generally rated for maximum load. If shorted, it will overheat and be likely to self destruct unless protected by a fuse or circuit breaker.